# Some text is unselectable in my HTML page. Need to make it selectable

Tags: html, css

I found a mobile web template, but its not clean. 1 major problem is some text is unselectable . please check http://codepen.io/rexmizan/pen/uAwke check "All Text of this box is unselectable" in ul class=box. you will find ul.box2 in CSS on line: 230

Please help me to fix my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Because `<div id="inner">` is on top of it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to give `z-index: 2` to your `ul.box2` css element, as there is some other element with same `z-index` overlapping it, so replace your following css:

```
ul.box2 {
position: relative;
z-index: 1; /* prevent shadows falling behind containers with backgrounds */
...
...
```

for this one:

```
ul.box2 {
position: relative;
z-index: 2; /* prevent shadows falling behind containers with backgrounds */
...
...
```

with above change is working fine, see the [**demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwKgk)

Comment: The z-index of `#inner` is 5, so `#box2` needs to be higher than 5.

Comment: Have you tried it? it is working fine with z-index: 2 , see it here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwKgk , so your assumption seems not be correct.

Comment: That is strange, but you are correct. It appears to be working.

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS you have `#inner:before` with `z-index:5;`. This appears to be putting a div over the `box2` which causes it to be selected instead of box2's contents. You can see this happen in Chrome when you right click on the text and choose `Inspect element`. The element it inspects is `#inner` not `#box2`.

Good luck.